# Getting the latest document in a collection

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have a collection of item. When I listen to it, I see I'm getting all the items all the time. I only need the latest document, I need to respond when a new document is added. I tried to limit the query like this:

```
    this.itemsCollection = this.afs.collection('games').doc(gameId)
        .collection('hands', ref => ref.orderBy('started').limit(1));
    this.items = this.itemsCollection.valueChanges();
    this.items.subscribe((hands: Hand[]) => {
      console.log('got hand ', hands);
    });
```

sadly, it doesn't work. I'm not getting any items when a new item is added. When I remove the limit function, I'm getting all the items every time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this is to add a Date property to each object in your collection, then simply query it according to this new property descending and call limit(1) function. You may check the documentation on how to ["Order and limit data with Cloud Firestore"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) and ["Get data with Cloud Firestore"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)

The idea is the following:

```
db.collection("YourCollection")
  .orderBy('Date', 'desc')
  .limit(1).get()
})
```

Let me know if this is helpful.